# Renci.SshNe's DownloadFile hangs after downloading some files from ftp server

Tags: c#, sftp

I have window service that downloads files from ftp server.Below is the code for downloading files. But It downloads 4-5 files and then stop at this line - 'sftp.DownloadFile(remoteDirectory + remoteFileName, file1)'. I'm using using Renci.SshNet ddl. How can i resume downloading if it stopes? if you could help me would be very great!

```
                    if (sftp.Exists(remoteDirectory))
                    {
                        var files = sftp.ListDirectory(remoteDirectory);

                        var filterfiles = (from a in files
                                           where (a.Name.StartsWith(FileInitial))
                                           select a).ToList();



                        foreach (var file in filterfiles)
                        {


                            string remoteFileName = file.Name;
                            if ((!file.Name.StartsWith(".")))
                            {
                                string[] arr1 = remoteFileName.Split('_');


                                if (arr1.Length > 2)
                                {


                                    using (Stream file1 = File.OpenWrite(localDirectory + remoteFileName))
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {

                                            sftp.DownloadFile(remoteDirectory + remoteFileName, file1);
                                        }
                                        catch(Exception Ex)
                                        {


                                        }


                                    }



                                }
                            }
                        }


                    }
```

Comment: Add some logging logic in catch or throw exception maybe there will be some helpful information.

Comment: *Log* the exception instead of hiding it. Or don't catch it at all. You can't fix errors if you discard them with `catch{}`. If you *don't* catch the exception the application will crash and you'll get the full exception text in the console or Windows Event log at least, allowing you to fix any problems

Comment: To resume or reconnect you need to know the exception's type and contents anyway. You can probably ignore a missing file error for example and try to download the *next* file. You can't do that if the exception was thrown due to a terminated connection or a network error. You'd have to retry the entire operation, from connnection to download

Comment: I am having a very similar issue with this library, when downloading larger files it occasionally will hang indefinitely, were you ever to figure out a workaround to this issue?